Using common part of supertrait and subtrait in struct
I am developing an interface that can create connections using TCPStream or SerialPort from this library.
I want to have a member of a struct that implements the traits std::io::Read and std::io::Write, which both of these connections provide.
SerialPort has trait SerialPort which is Send + std::io::Read + std::io::Write link
I have came up with this code:
trait ReadWriteIo: Read + Write {}

impl ReadWriteIo for TcpStream {}
impl ReadWriteIo for Box<dyn SerialPort> {}

struct ServerInterface {
    connection: Box<dyn ReadWriteIo>,
    // some other members
}

impl ServerInterface {
    fn new(use_tcp: bool) -> Result<ServerInterface> {
        let parser = MspParser::new();

        if use_tcp {
            let connection = TcpStream::connect("example:8080")?;

            return Ok(ServerInterface {
                connection: Box::new(connection),
                // other members
            });
        }

        // creates Box<dyn SerialPort>
        let connection = serialport::new("/dev/ttyUSB0", DEFAULT_BAUD_RATE)
            .timeout(time::Duration::from_millis(10))
            .open()?;

        Ok(ServerInterface {
            // this gives error
            // rustc: mismatched types
            // expected struct `Box<(dyn ReadWriteIo + 'static)>`
            // found struct `Box<dyn SerialPort>`
            connection,
        })
    }
}

From what I understand, my issue is that the compiler does not want to accept that Box<dyn SerialPort> can be Box<dyn ReadWriteIo>, which is essentially its subtrait.
Is it possible to achieve this? Or maybe should I switch to an enum? Using traits would be nicer for me as I am only using Read and Write, so no other changes in the code are necessary.

Nit: you can achieve the same with a blanket impl: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc4137d00c59fbadfd9483f8a5bc2898.

The easiest way will be to wrap the Box<dyn SerialPort> (that impls ReadWriteIo with Box and convert that to Box<dyn ReadWriteIo>:
trait ReadWriteIo: Read + Write {}

impl ReadWriteIo for TcpStream {}
impl ReadWriteIo for Box<dyn SerialPort> {}

struct ServerInterface {
    connection: Box<dyn ReadWriteIo>,
    // some other members
}

impl ServerInterface {
    fn new(use_tcp: bool) -> Result<ServerInterface> {
        let parser = MspParser::new();

        if use_tcp {
            let connection = TcpStream::connect("example:8080")?;

            return Ok(ServerInterface {
                connection: Box::new(connection),
                // other members
            });
        }

        // creates Box<dyn SerialPort>
        let connection = serialport::new("/dev/ttyUSB0", DEFAULT_BAUD_RATE)
            .timeout(time::Duration::from_millis(10))
            .open()?;

        Ok(ServerInterface {
            connection: Box::new(connection),
        })
    }
}

This will be slightly less efficient since it will involve double allocation, indirection and dynamic dispatch, but it should be fine most of the times.

Thanks! This helped and solved my issue.
